# Distribute video feed from Pi to multiple network clients

Tags: networking, camera, streaming-video, webcam

I want to set up a webcam for a fish tank on the LAN at my office. I set up a Raspberry Pi model 3B with a camera and used https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer to stream it locally. It works great, but every time an additional client opens up the URL in a browser, the frame rate drops.

I would like to set up a server that would take the feed from the Pi and distribute it to multiple clients, so each new connection loads the server and not the Pi. Is there a tool available for doing this type of thing? My searches have been fruitless so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can live stream video to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Alternatively, you can run your own rtmp service: [owncast](https://owncast.online/).